# EF Codefirst get POCO's configuration

Tags: c#, .net, code-first

I have a POCO object (EF Code-first)

```
public class ExampleTestOfDataTypes
{
        public string StringProp { get; set; }
}
```

Than i have its configuration class:

```
public class ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExampleTestOfDataTypes>
    {
        public ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig()
        {
            ToTable("CustomTableName");
            this.Property(m => m.StringProp).HasColumnName("CustomString");
        }
    }
```

How can i get the new Tablename and new StringProp name when i changed it in config file (considering i have ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig  and ExampleTestOfDataTypes)

Thanks

Comment: Override OnModelCreating method in your context class and then add it `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig());`

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted. i don't need to register the config class i need to read its properties and settings.

Comment: you need to register it. otherwise EF won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what's inside the mappings file, try this method:

```
void ExportMappings(DbContext context, string edmxFile)  
{  
     var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };  
     using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(edmxFile, settings))  
     {  
         System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(context, writer);  
     }  
}
```

It will export all of your custom settings to an xml file. It's better to name it .edmx and then VS.NET will be able to open it automatically.